# Logical OR of 2 indicator columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two indicator variable columns.  I would like to create a 3rd column that is the logical `OR` of the two existing columns.  I am able to, like this:

```
df      = DataFrame ({"a" : [1,0,0] , "b" : [0,0,1] })
df["c"] = (df["a"] | df["b"]).apply(lambda x : 1 if x else 0)
```

The series produced by `(df["a"] | df["b"])` is of type `bool`. This surprised me because `|` is a bitwise operator, so I expected the series to be of type `int`. Thus, I have to do the `apply(lambda ...)` to get the desired `int` column.

Am I doing this correctly or is there a more succinct/pandas-preferred/pythonic way?

Comment: What version numpy, pandas are you using as I can't reproduce your boolean df, it just works correctly for me, I'm running numpy 1.9.1 and pandas 0.16.1, calling `astype(int)` would solve your problem but I can't reproduce your error

Comment: I'm glad you asked me the versions, it looks like my pandas is only 0.15.2. The `astype(int)` solution works fine but I will upgrade right now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `astype`:

```
df["c"] = (df["a"] | df["b"]).astype(int)
```

The `|` is not really the bitwise operator. It will call the method `__or__`.
This can be implemented as desired.

So this:

```
 df['a'] | df['b']
```

actually calls this:

```
 df['a'].__or__(df['b'])
```

Comment: Ah, so `__or__()` is to `|` just as `__eq__()` is to `==`, and `Series` implements `__or__()` as returning a `bool`, correct?  This would explain it.  I guess there is no standard object method that is triggered by the `or` operator, correct?

Comment: Got it.  So the decision for `Series.__or__()` to return a `bool` instead of an `int` was motivated by the fact that there had to be some kind of boolean comparison of `Series`, but with no `object` method for `or`, the `__or__()` method and `|` operator were the only way to go?  And this explains why you can't `or` two `Series` instances?  Sorry for all the questions, just trying to understand this.

Comment: Yes, `or` is a reserved keyword. Hence, it is not possibly to change how it works. On the other hand, special methods such as `__or__` are designed to be changed. A Series of bools can be used for indexing. This would not work in a useful way with integers.